# program crashes while using realloc

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, realloc

I am given a text file of unknown size and i have to read it till the end, calculate the number of words, letters and some other stuff. To do this i try to read the entire file and save all the words in an array. I am told to use dynamic memory allocation since i don't know the size of the text file beforehand.

Before i get into the algorithm for calculating the words and letters i am trying to make the dynamic memory allocation work. This is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE *fp; // file pointer

    //defining a dynamic string array

    char **array = malloc(10 * sizeof(char *)); //10 rows for now, will be   dynamically changed later

    int i,size = 10, current = 0; // current points to the position of the next slot to be filled

    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        array[i] = malloc(20); //the max word size will be 20 characters (char size = 1 byte)
    }


    fillArray(fp, array, current, size);

    return 0;
}
```

I define an array of strings, a variable showing its size, and a variable pointing to the slot where the next element will be added.
The functions are as follows:

```
int fillArray(FILE *fp, char **p, int ptr, int size){

    puts("What's the name of the file (and format) to be accessed?\n (It has to be in the same directory as the program)");
    char str[20];
    gets(str);  //getting the answer
    fp = fopen((const char *)str, "r"); //opening file


    int x=0, i=0, j;

    while(x!=EOF){ // looping till we reach the end of the file
        printf("current size: %d , next slot: %d\n", size, ptr);
        if(ptr>=size){
            printf("increasing size\n");
            addSpace(p, &size);
        }
        x = fscanf(fp, "%19s", p[i]);
        puts(p[i]);
        i++;
        ptr++;
    }

}

void addSpace(char **p, int *size){ //remember to pass &size
    //each time this is called, 10 more rows are added to the array
    p = realloc(p,*size + 10);
    int i;
    for(i=*size; i<(*size)+10; i++){
        p[i] = malloc(20);
    }
    *size += 10;
}

void freeSpace(char **p, int ptr){
    //each time this is called, the rows are reduced so that they exactly fit the content
    p = realloc(p, ptr); //remember that ptr points to the position of the last occupied slot + 1

}
```

At the beginning, the rows of the array are 10. Each time the words of the text don't fit the array, the function `addSpace` is called adding 10 more rows. The program runs succesfully 3 times (reaching 30 rows) and then crashes.

After using printf's to find out where the program crashes (because i am not used to the debugger yet), it seems that it crashes while trying to add 10 more rows (to 40). I can't figure out the problem or how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you `malloc(20)`, the maximum string length is **19** characters; the 20th character will be the `\0`. Also you should realloc `*size + 10 * sizeof *p`!

Comment: 'addSpace(p, &size);' cannot modify 'p' which, if it's a reallocated pointer, is a big problem:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic!

You are also passing in a double pointer which is `realloc`d, the address has changed between the caller and callee.

Also there's a `realloc` issue.

```
p = realloc(p,*size + 10);
```

If `realloc` fails, the original pointer to block of memory is clobbered.

The proper way to do this:

```
char **tmp_ptr = realloc(p, *size + 10);
if (tmp_ptr == NULL){
   perror("Out of memory");
}else{
    p = tmp_ptr;
}
return p;
```

You can do it another way, either return back the address of the new block or use triple pointers.

```
void addSpace(char ***p, int *size){ //remember to pass &size
    //each time this is called, 10 more rows are added to the array
    char **tmp_ptr = realloc(*p, *size + 10);
    if (tmp_ptr == NULL){
       perror("Out of memory");
    }else{
        *p = tmp_ptr;
    }
    int i;
    for(i=*size; i<(*size)+10; i++){
        *p[i] = malloc(20);
    }
    *size += 10;
}
```

And from the caller

```
addSpace(&p, &size);
```

Comment: Oh, it's much worse than that:(

Comment: @MartinJames spotted it bit late... soz!

Comment: But that would mean i can't read any more words right? However the file contains 70 words, and possible more. Isn't there a way to be able to add them all?

Comment: @Alan sure.  Pass 'p' by address or, much more friendly, return p from addSpace() instead of void.

Comment: @t0mm13b One thing if i may. If i were to return the pointer, then the function declaration should be `char **addSpace(...)` correct? Because i am getting a `conflicting types` error

Answer (score 3):

C is pass by value. The pointer `p` is passed to `addSpace(p, &size);`, and a copy of that pointer is created in the function. Once the copy is changed: `p = realloc(p,*size + 10);` the original stays the same.

After the realloc call, the original pointer is not valid anymore. Using it causes undefined behavior, a crash in your case.

Return the new value and assign it to the original pointer:

```
p = addSpace( p , &size );
```

Comment: But it already worked 2 times,  if that's the case it shouldn't work at all right?

Comment: @Alan No, working correctly is one of the results of undefined behavior.

Comment: @Alan deliver it/hand it in/whatever, and it will then break.   UB is malicious like that:(